# Can't find Onlyoffice .docx file

Tags: directory

When i was saving my .docx file in Onlyoffice it saved in a default directory and i can't find it anymore. I don't know why but my default directory changed to /snap/onlyofficedesktopeditors/21/opt/onlyoffice/desktopeditors

And when i'm trying to reach it i can't find "opt" folder in "21" folder.
What should i do?

P.S.
This file is very important so i really need to find it.

[Onlyoffice save window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohhVh.png)

[no opt folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvzjA.png)

Comment: Did you install OnlyOffice through a snap?  Snapped programs tend to run in their own type of isolated section of the drive, typically, which explains why it's in a 'nonstandard' location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no idea where the file could be, you can search for it with the command

`find / -name "your_file_name.docx" 2> /dev/null`

which searches the whole disk and discards any error messages (like permission denied to access system folders). This can take some time...

If you don't know the exact name of your file either, you can search for all .docx files with

`find / -name "*.docx" 2> /dev/null`

To enter these commands, open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T

Comment: Thank you for help. I didn't find it but you saved some time for me. So now i'm sure that it's deleted from the drive.